# setState with array from onChange of <select> avoid the change of the <select> label

Tags: reactjs

**TL;DR:** calling this.setState to update an array avoid the change of a < select > label with the selected < option >

**Explanations:**
I am building an array of options like that (dd is for drop down):

```
let ddUsers = (this.state.users.map(user => <option key={uuid.v4()} value={user.key}>{user.name}</option>))
```

Then here is my select:

```
<select onChange={this.handleFilter}>{ddUsers}</select>
```

This works perfectly: it appears first with the first option and is able to display the others.

Here is my onChange function: handleFilter

```
handleFilter = (event) => {

    let selectedUsers;

    console.log(event.target.value, this.state.DEFAULT_KEY)
    if (event.target.value === this.state.DEFAULT_KEY) {
        selectedUsers = [...this.state.users];
    } else {
        selectedUsers = (this.state.users.filter(user => user.key === event.target.value));
    }

    // this.setState({selected: selectedUsers}); <-- The problem comes from this line (looks like atleast)

}
```

Now with the commented last line, the label of the select correctly update to the selected options. But when I uncomment this line, the function is called, this.state.selected is updated **BUT** the select is blocked on the 1st option.

Is that clear? What am I missing?

**In fact:** just calling setState in the function avoid the correct change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are setting the `key` of `option` to dynamic value which gets updated every time. Try to use a know and unique one as the `key`. Code such as below

```
<option key={user.key} value={user.key}>
```

This ensures, you have unique key and also is predictable.